# Tagging std::function with a name?

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11, std-function

I'm working on a parser combinator library, and I'd really like my parser to simply be some callable object:

```
typedef std::function<parse_result(parse_stream)> parser;
```

Which makes the parser combinators nice, eg:

```
parser operator &(parser a, parser b) { return both(a,b); }
```

*but* I'd like two features:

1) I'd like string literals to get promoted to a parser automatically so you can do things like:

```
parser option = "<" & regexp("[^+>]+");
```

2) I'd like a parser to have a name that I can use for error formatting.  In the case of the "both" parser above, I could print that I expected a.name() and b.name() for example.

The two options I've tried so far are

1. a parser class that's callable, this lets me build from strings and std::function instances *but* a general callable has to be converted to a std::function first and from there to a parser, and C++ won't do two implicit conversions
2. Inheriting from std::function so I can implicitly convert the functions, but this seems to have a lot of gotchas in terms of only converting callables into a parser.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to structure this?

Comment: How about `"<"_p`?

Comment: @Quentin is referring to [user-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal).

Comment: As in a custom suffix?  Hadn't thought of that...

Comment: are you not able to use something existing, e.g. [boost::spirit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html)?

Comment: @Caleth I want to write my own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want a raw typedef of std function; your parser is more than a any std function.

```
struct parser: std::function<parse_result(parse_stream)>{
  using base = std::function<parse_result(parse_stream)>;
  using base::base;
};
```

this should permit

```
parser p = []( parse_stream str ) { return parse_result(7); };
```

as we use inheriting constructors to expose the raw `std::function` ctors in `parser`.

While you can override:

```
parser operator&(parser a, parser b) { return both(a,b); }
```

with the typedef version by putting `&` in the namespace of `parse_result` or `parse_stream`, I'd advise against it; there has been chat in the standarizatoin to restrict that kind of template-argument ADL.  With a bare `parser` type, the spot to put such operator overloads is clear.

In addition some types cannot be overloaded outside of the class, like `&=`.  With a `struct` you can do it in there.

None of this fixes

```
parser option = "<" & regexp("[^+>]+");
```

as the problem here is that the right hand side has no idea what the left hand side is doing (unless `regexp` is a function returing a parser).

First do this:

```
struct parser: std::function<parse_result(parse_stream)>{
  using base = std::function<parse_result(parse_stream)>;
  parser( char const* str ):
    base( [str=std::string(str)](parse_stream stream)->parse_result { /* do work */ } )
  {}
  parser( char c ):
    base( [c](parse_stream str)->parse_result { /* do work */ } )
  {}
  using base::base;
};
```

then you can add

```
namespace parsing {
  // parser definition goes here
  inline namespace literals {
    inline parser operator""_p( char const* str ) { return str; }
  }
}
```

and `using namespace parsing::literals` means `"hello"_p` is a parser that attempts to parse the string `"hello"`.

Comment: Inheriting constructors, that's what I was missing, this is brilliant, thank you!